Taylor's Theorem for functions on the Rational Numbers
I have been looking for different proofs of the Taylor's Theorem with Peano form of the remainder. But all proofs I have found use some form of the Mean Value Theorem or L'Hôpital's Rule (which also seems to need some form of the Mean Value Theorem).
Now, the Mean Value Theorem depends on the topology of $\mathbb{R}$. I used to believe that the Peano form of the remainder could be proved by more elementary means, only using the definition of the derivative (which is equivalent to Taylor's Theorem for $n = 1$).
So I ask: is the theorem true for a function $f\colon \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$? Or does it depend on some property of $\mathbb{R}$?

All of calculus collapses to trivial statements without the completeness of $\mathbb{R}$. Limits don't even necessarily exist!

Can you give an example of a function $f\colon\Bbb Q\to\Bbb Q$ that is differentiable at the origin but that does not extend to a function $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ that is differentiable at the origin?

@TedShifrin I can't. I believe there is one, but this is beside the point. I am only saying $\mathbb{Q}$ because I wanted a proof without the completeness of $\mathbb{R}$. It seems possible given the simplicity of the statement, but now I believe it is not the case.

This $f\colon \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$ rules out a lot of functions normally considers. However, the “trivial” part of calculus can be developed without completeness, for example the product rule works. The  introductory book Numbers and functions steps into analysis, by Burn does this.
